# safely handling a mix of markdown and html in rendering and storing

Tags: html, .net, parsing, xss, markdown

I'm planning to use [EpicEditor](http://epiceditor.com/) as an editor for a blog engine, my current stack is AngularJS, ServiceStack, and RavenDB. The issue here, I want to deliver both safe html and markdown markup to the data store and of course restore the actual representation when fetched, the issue is I want to preserve safe html tags and add some functions to embed videos for example,

First trial used the following sequence:

- editing done
- posted to the api
- raw text from the editor is encoded and saved

Now for displaying the edited data:

- fetch encoded string
- return it as response
- parse it with built-in parser (Marked.js)

The previous process is broken of course, for example the `<h1>` tags are rendered to be displayed, this is mainly because of the `HttpUtility/WebUtility` way of handling the html encoding. it becomes difficult to distinguish what is to be displayed as `code` for example and what is to be rendered like embedded `<iframe>` for a video.

When I post some markdown/html markup like the following:

```
#Hello, World

>>> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Skl71urqKu0

<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/veJZDANY6go" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<h1>huhuhu</h1>

<script>alert("fail")</script>

    <script>alert("win")</script>
```

This is what I get from my `WebUtility.HtmlEcode()`:

```
{
    "status": "#Hello, World\n\n&gt;&gt;&gt; http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Skl71urqKu0\n\n&lt;iframe width=&#39;420&#39; height=&#39;315&#39; src=&#39;http://www.youtube.com/embed/veJZDANY6go&#39; frameborder=&#39;0&#39; allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;\n\n&lt;h1&gt;huhuhu&lt;/h1&gt;\n\n&lt;script&gt;alert(&#39;fail&#39;)&lt;/script&gt;\n\n    &lt;script&gt;alert(&#39;win&#39;)&lt;/script&gt;"
}
```

The previous encoded string also breaks in terms of displaying the actual code after parsing with **Marked.js** I get for example magically added `&` in my XSS attempt which even breaks the displaying of the code. For clarification, it would look like this:

```
<pre><code>&amp;lt;script&amp;gt;alert(&amp;#39;win&amp;#39;)&amp;lt;/script&amp;gt;</code></pre>
```

I'm aware that there is ***antixss*** library that can sanitize the code but does that make it completely safe to store in a database?

Also I was thinking of parsing the actual links and building the embedding string on the server instead of allowing handling raw html, is this feasible?

Sorry for the lengthy post and thanks in advance!

Comment: This question seems very .NET specific. Marked.js handles Markdown + HTML mixed great, and converting HTML tags to something else shouldn't affect Marked. Your first example works if you just use Marked. The problem seems to be with your HtmlEncode functions.

Comment: For this: "Also I was thinking of parsing the actual links and building the embedding string on the server instead of allowing handling raw html, is this feasible?" you may want to open a different question. XSS and converting strings to embeddable elements can be it's own answer :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I've noticed that Marked.js actually parses the alert statements without executing them, do you think this is safe to use? because if so I can just store my exported string and store it and essentially rely on marked.js in terms of safety. sorry if this sounds dumb :P

Comment: Parse doesn't execute them because it's just a string to Marked. same as if you just typed `var x = '<script>alert("test");</script>'`. EpicEditor in turn doesn't execute them when you preview because Marked parses HTML entities to be like `<script>alert(&#39;...`. This causes a JS error. However, anything without quotes would still execute.

Comment: Again tho, you dont want to rely on front-end because I could make a manual XHR request to your POST endpoint and send a script tag bypassing the editor altogether.

Comment: True thing, I think I will just rely on the fact that the blog owner wont be attacking site visitors. this editor will mainly be visible to authenticated/authorized users so in general it wont be exposed to any random 'user input', I've had short tweets about with with Troy Hunt, and he said that he had to submit scripts to his blog at some point so it's not totally useless I believe. Feel free to let me know whether this is a good idea or not. thx